# SHA512 Salt Php

Tags: php

I want to generate a token using SHA512+Salt+String in PHP, which is something like this `$qs=$_GET['t']`, `$salt='randomString'`, and base on those strings hash them using SHA512, anyone can help?

My account got blocked by some down votes questions, the funny thing is I have to re-edit them, even though I already have the accepted answer.I do not understand what's the point to do this.I am so frustrated by this stackoverflow system.

Now, I basically can do nothing but keep editing my questions, and they have all been answered. This is ridiculous !!!

Comment: Maybe [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)?

Comment: @Jeff but there is no salt option

Comment: just concatanate the salt to the string (at front, at the end,..).

Comment: this comment http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php#94104 is older, but describes salting dos and don'ts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) PHP method:

```
<?php
echo hash ( "sha512", $salt . $_GET["t"]);
?>
```

The *salt* is just a random text prefixed at the password, to avoid the use of "rainbow tables" (database of password/hash pairs of common passwords), because you've a salt prefix.

You can also store the salt separated at database or use a separator character, for example:

```
<?php
echo $salt . "#" . hash ( "sha512", $salt . $_GET["t"]);
?>
```

To check the password, you can use:

```
<?php
// $dbhash contains the result of hash with salt separated by "#".
if ( hash ( "sha512", substr ( $dbhash, 0, strpos ( $dbhash, "#")) . $_GET["t"]) == substr ( $dbhash, strpos ( $dbhash, "#") + 1))
{
  echo "Password match!";
} else {
  echo "Invalid password!";
}
?>
```

Comment: not my vote, but this should not be used for passwords. For that use  `password_hash` . note the OP may no reference to passwords.

Comment: @IdontDownVote sure! Just answering the question. The ultimate password hash storage security must use PBKDF2() method. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php)

Comment: except passwords were never mentioned in the question.

Comment: Sure, my mistake. Hash with salt points me to passwords, but it's really not mentioned. Thanks for pointing this!

Comment: ...and there are other ways to do secure password hashing than pbkdf2